# Get height of an element containing the height of all its children

Tags: javascript, html

I search for an option to get the height of an element with the height of all its children.

## Example

I want to know the full height of the body of following site with an inline scroll container (https://simon-frey.eu/splashTest/container.html):

```html
<html><head>
<style>
        body,div{
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        div{
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>
11<br>
12<br>
13<br>
14<br>
15<br>
16<br>
17<br>
18<br>
19<br>
20
</div>

</body></html>
```

Using the options I found so far I only get the height of the body (100% window height):

```
document.body.scrollHeight

document.body.clientHeight

getComputedStyle(document.body).height
```

**If the window has 1000px height and the content inside of it has 2000px height, all this options return 1000px instead of the 2000px I want to get.**

Answer (score 0):

That's because your `<body>` element is actually not scrolling, but the nested `<div>` is, since you have set `overflow: hidden` to the body but `overflow-y: auto` for the `<div>`.

So if you want to get the height of all the content on the page, then you need to query for that `<div>` and access its `scrollHeight` property.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.scroller').scrollHeight);
```

```html
<html><head>
<style>
        body,div.scroller{
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            font-size: 3em;
        }
        div.scroller{
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="scroller">
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
9<br>
10<br>
11<br>
12<br>
13<br>
14<br>
15<br>
16<br>
17<br>
18<br>
19<br>
20
</div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I know that is the reason, but is there a general solution for getting the height of the complete body, even with this kind of edge cases included?For my application I need this to work on sites, where I do not know about certain properties beforehand and thereby I can not adapt individual to every service :/

Comment: @SimonFrey You can't, since you need to guess which element holds all the overflowing element. What happens if a site has multiple wrappers? How are you going to compute that?

Comment: What do you think about a recursive solution: If a child has a bigger size than the parent, return child height and than iterate over the whole DOM? Seems quite in-performant though :/